# Sorting groups based on Group ItemCount

Tags: wpf, sorting, grouping, listcollectionview

On a `ListCollectionView`, i just add new `GroupDescriptions`.
But i am looking a way to sort them based on the `ItemCount` of the groups.

So at first position i would get the group with the most items.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the groups in another view and sort that.

XAML example:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Items2" Source="{Binding Groups,
                                                      Source={StaticResource Items}}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="ItemCount" Direction="Descending"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the suggestion, but i m looking for a cleaner solution, may be in codebehind?

Comment: @myCollections: How exactly would code behind be cleaner? I for one think this method *is* clean and it can easily be translated to code behind if you really want to...

Answer (score 0):

I've created a custom ListCollectionView to make top level group sorting possible, using a great library [System.Linq.Dynamic](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/):

```
Public Class ListCollectionViewEx
    Inherits ListCollectionView
    Private _groupSortDescriptions As SortDescriptionCollection
    Private _groups As ReadOnlyObservableCollection(Of Object)

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property GroupSortDescriptions As SortDescriptionCollection
        Get
            Return Me._groupSortDescriptions
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Groups As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyObservableCollection(Of Object)
        Get
            If Me._groupSortDescriptions.Count > 0 Then
                If Me._groups Is Nothing AndAlso
                    MyBase.Groups IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim qs As String = String.Join(
                        ",",
                        Me._groupSortDescriptions.
                        Select(Function(gsd) String.Format("{0} {1}", gsd.PropertyName, If(gsd.Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending, "ASC", "DESC"))).
                        ToArray)

                    Dim sortedGroups = MyBase.Groups.
                        Select(Function(g) DirectCast(g, CollectionViewGroup)).
                        AsQueryable.OrderBy(qs).
                        AsEnumerable

                    If sortedGroups IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                        sortedGroups.Count > 0 Then
                        Me._groups = New ReadOnlyObservableCollection(Of Object)(New ObservableCollection(Of Object)(sortedGroups))
                    End If
                End If

                Return Me._groups
            End If

            Return MyBase.Groups
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(collection As IEnumerable)
        MyBase.New(collection)
        Me._groupSortDescriptions = New SortDescriptionCollection()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Usage:

```
View.GroupSortDescriptions.Add(New SortDescription("ItemCount", ListSortDirection.Descending))
```